# Installing versions prior to Python 3.9 on 21.04

Tags: apt, python, dependencies

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 21.04 as I prefer not to use the LTS releases (i.e. have later packages). I've been working on a new codebase happily with the default Python 3.9

But for an older project that runs on Python 3.6, I want to also install a version prior to 3.9 (I've hit a packaging issue around a version 3.9 issue https://github.com/hzdg/django-enumfields/commit/8a54ab6ca1a406b4f736b1d8a1daff49431a1c5c but I'd much rather have 3.6 or 3.7 available for my virtualenv's as needed, than put in a 3.9 specific fix for a codebase that runs on 3.6 at present).

I've installed the deadsnakes ppa with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` and done an update. But then trying to install an earlier python version, I get a dependency issue (presumably because it's a focal package)

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.7 : Depends: libpython3.7-stdlib (= 3.7.12-1+focal1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: If you need many versions of Python, and prefer more up-to-date packages,  Miniconda may be a good choice. It also works cross platform.

Comment: The deadsnakes PPA is only for LTS versions of Ubuntu.  @Ben maybe write an answer with how to configure miniconda with python3.6.

Comment: Thanks @Ben  Anaconda always struck me as a huge collection but I wasn't aware of miniconda. I'll see how I progress and update here if it works for me.

Answer (score -1):

You should compile it yourself. Use:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/<version>/Python-<version>.tgz
tar xzvf Python-<version>.tgz
cd Python-<version>
./configure
make
```

while `<version>` is a valid python version, e.g. `3.7.0`.

Comment: This may overwrite or collide with the system installed Python - usually I suggest `pyenv` be used here for creating userspace Python installs that won't conflict.

Comment: @ThomasWard Removed `sudo make install`.

Comment: Without make install, you system will be remain unchanged, so don't worry.